# Changing bottom navigation bar icon colour?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-navigation-bar

This is what my bottom navigation bar looks like at the moment:

[image]

Looks great right? Except that, right now you can see each icon clearly (or mostly clearly), however when you view it on my device you can barely make out the icons at all.

I have the following in my `themes.xml` at the moment:

```
...
<!-- Navigation bar colour. -->
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/pink</item>
<item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">false</item><!-- This does nothing -->
...
```

At the moment my `minSdkVersion` is 29 and my `targetSdkVersion` is 30.

How could I change the icons colour, or if that's not possible, at least have them a darker colour so they can be viewable?

Comment: What's your phone model? I think behavior may be different for different phones. Have you tried to run your code on android emulator?

Comment: To make icons *darker* you should set `windowLightNavigationBar` flag to `true`, not `false`.

Comment: I've tried to do that but unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried to run your code on other devices or emulator? It may be a device specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change color of navigation bar icons. But you can make it dark or light. Your pink navigation bar looks pretty light. So, set `windowLightNavigationBar` to `true`:

```xml
<item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I've tried to do that but unfortunately it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You could make it lighter only

Answer (score 0):

**Please try to this**

```
 <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
```

should be right. but you said it doens't work.
So I assumed there is another theme on your activity.

So, I sugest, in your activitiy or fragment code, how about set window flag directly.
try code below . It will make your icon dark

```
activity.window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're in the `themes.xml` file- have you tried adding this to the `styles.xml` file?

```xml
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/black</item>
```

Also, this [Styles and Themes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes) page might help you out! They have a comparison and pretty good explanations with examples. For example, you can customize the default theme that you're using like this:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```